# Sync Framework failing on invalid data

Tags: sql-server, microsoft-sync-framework

Running SQL '12 and Sync Framework.  Sometimes I'm seeing a sync failure due to a FK violation because sync framework is trying to insert a row into the remote DB with a null value for the FK.  Hooking to the SqlSyncProvider ApplyChangeFailed event and examining the Conflict.RemoteChange data table confirms that it's trying to insert a row that only has it's PK filled out and all other columns null.  My question is, how is it that the local sync framework triggers are picking up this insert when it would be impossible to do (due to several columns being set as NOT NULL)?

Comment: is that a row that was inserted and deleted before it was synched? or is it a row whose PK value was changed after inserting?

Comment: PK value was changed after insert...and I now know Sync Framework does not handle changes to PK.